# webcam does not work in pip version of opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, webcam

I've been facing a problem with the webcam in opencv in python using anaconda.

The problem is the following:
I cannot open the webcam if opencv is installed via any of the two:
`pip install opencv-python`            (available 3.1,3.2,3.3), or
`pip install opencv-contrib-python`   (available 3.2,3.3)

However it will work if and only if I install it from 
`conda install opencv`       (available opencv 3.1)

However, some functionality of opencv is only given in newer versions or in the contrib version currently not available via conda.
Does anyone have an idea why the pip versions won't work?

**Update => The Pip Packgage on pypi is not linked against FFMPEG for linux:** 
`conda install -c conda-forge opencv` provides 3.3 but without contrib 
 => if other version is needed building from source is required

Here the code used to use the webcam:
(Yes I tried various variations suggested

```
import cv2
print (cv2.__version__)
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #tried -1,0,1,...

if camera.isOpened(): # isOpened is always False for pip version
    print ("successfully opened Webcam")
else:
    print ("Webcam error")  
success,img = camera.read() # success is always False for pip version
print (success,img.shape)
camera.release()
```

---

I tried various webcams, and various alternations to the code as suggested on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying libraries are not linked in the `pip` package. This was a design choice for the package to be more universally installable.

From the Python Package Index (PyPI) [documentation for the opencv-python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python):

> **Q: Why I can’t open video files on GNU/Linux distribution X or on macOS?**
>
> A: OpenCV video I/O depends heavily on FFmpeg. Manylinux and macOS OpenCV binaries are not compiled against it. The purpose of these packages is to provide as easy as possible installation experience for OpenCV Python bindings and they should work directly out-of-the-box. Adding FFmpeg as an additional dependency without a “universal” FFmpeg build (e.g. LGPL licensed build like in the Windows wheels) the goal is considerably harder to achieve. This might change in the future.

You could compile OpenCV from source if you want to use the newer versions and not have these problems. There's a number of such tutorials. OpenCV has  a Python specific tutorial for [compiling on Windows](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html) and [on Fedora](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html#install-opencv-python-in-fedora). Additionally, PyImageSearch has a very popular number of blog posts on compiling OpenCV from source on macOS and Linux: [Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/), [Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/20/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-3-4-on-ubuntu/), [macOS](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/05/macos-install-opencv-3-and-python-3-5/), [macOS via Homebrew](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) (with an accompanying [troubleshooting article](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/05/15/resolving-macos-opencv-homebrew-install-errors/)), along with a number of other Linux flavors (e.g. Raspbian) and posts for older Python versions; just search the web if that doesn't cover you.

Comment: honestly if really opencv can't open a webcam if it is not built against ffmpeg than it should throw an exception or print a warning if someone tries to use that functionality! Anything else is just creating unnecessary debug time and frustration...

Comment: @Max well people who make Python packages certainly shouldn't be modifying the source code of another project to fit in error codes specific to their installers. But yeah, the installer should let people know. Note it does work on Windows. Even simple functionality like `imshow()` and other various methods that invoked `highgui` didn't work with `opencv-python` on non-Windows machines but I think they've finally added support for that in the newer versions if I'm not mistaken. Anyways if this answered your question would you mind selecting it as the accepted solution? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Alexander, thank you for your in depth reply!

This openCV pip packge is currently one of the main sources of installation for pre built binaries for openCV... 
It would be great if someone could tell the people at OpenCV that they could provide a hint in their documentation for webcam usage [1](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d43/tutorial_py_video_display.html) as well since "check if proper versions of ffmpeg ... are installed", is completely misleading in this case!

Also some function like the cv2.selectROI() do throw errors that some packge is missing...

Comment: @Max it doesn't matter whether it is a main source that people use IMO---it's not recommended by OpenCV for installation and they are not responsible for third-party installers, and the documentation for the installer clearly states the issue. Further OpenCV would have to change their source code pending changes to the installer. But we can agree to disagree on this. IMO part of the reason this installer is used so often is it works cross-platform nicely, partly because they leave out pieces of the underlying library.

Comment: Well what does it cost if they state something like:
"Watch out - some widely used installers for pip do not link against ffmpeg and therefore do not work for webcams"
What does it save? - Precious time of debugging...

Anyway, thank you for your help and the explanations - clarified a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall the opencv-contrib-python libary, and re-install opencv-python and opencv-python-headless

Answer (score 0):

The following code resolved this issue for me:

```
video = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```