# Read after Videocapture on opencv always returns false

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, video-capture, video-processing

I cant figure out what the problem is.

I am using

- Ubuntu 17.04
- Python 2.7.13
- OpenCV Version: 3.3.0

I have gone through all the related problems on internet but have not got the solution for the problem yet.
'v.mp4' file is in the same directory in which my python file is present.

**CODE**

```
import cv2
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('v.mp4')
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0; 
print success
while success:
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    cv2.imwrite("frame%d.jpg" % count, image)     # save frame as JPEG file
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: can you try to change your file so it is `while vidcap.isOpened()` ? Can you ensure the file is being read? Also try displaying the frame first using `cv2.imshow()` before writing it?

Comment: How did you install OpenCV?

Comment: @SamerTufail I have already tried while vidcap.isOpened(), but it never enters the while loop. I am not sure that my code is able to read the file on the first place. Since success value always  remains false, there is no point of doing cv2.imshow() for now.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds i have installed opencv using                                 
 `$pip install opencv-python`

Comment: @arjungupta can you try any other file? maybe the file you have is corrupted?

Comment: It's normally good practice to check the return status of function calls - especially when things aren't working. Try using an absolute path to your video file - e.g. put in in `/tmp` and open `/tmp/video.mp4`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have copied my video file to `/tmp` and changed code to `vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture('/tmp/v.mp4')`, no change in result is observed, success value is still false.

Comment: @SamerTufail I have tried this code with many video files of different formats(mp4 and avi) which are surely not corrupted. –

Comment: It's because you installed OpenCV with `opencv-python`.

Comment: @arjungupta can you check if its the problem with the first frame getting stuck, try the code I pasted here: https://pastebin.com/hkASrULV at the very start and check if the return code succeeds in its read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `opencv-python` package does not have `VideoCapture()` support outside of Windows. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527000/webcam-does-not-work-in-pip-version-of-opencv-python-and-opencv-contrib-python/46527129#46527129) or the [PyPI `opencv-python` documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python), which states:

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**
>
> MacOS and Linux packages do not support video related functionality (not compiled with FFmpeg).

Comment: So, should I compile OpenCV from source if I don't want  these type of problems as explained by you in your other answer?

Comment: @arjungupta yep! If you aren't familiar with compiling stuff from source it can be a bit of a headache, but you'll get comfortable with it after a few tries :). If this answered your question, could you select it as accepted? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your advice, that really helped. I found how to compile open cv from source from [https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) , but that was tutorial was supported for Ubuntu 16.04, so I downgraded my OS from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 16.04 as  many of the libraries were not available for Ubuntu 17.04 that were very necessary for my project.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I used pycharm as my ide.  Every isopened() and read() showed up false. All I had to do to was change the python version that pycharm used to python 2.