# Are there issues with openCV 3 for python 3 on mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am not able to read the video file using .VideoCapture('filename.avi') constructor in mac using opencv3 with python3. It opens the file but .read() method is returning (false, none).

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You have a while loop. When is it returning that? Have you read the documentation why it would return that instead of assuming it's a bug?

Comment: This code is from the documentation. it works well on windows but not on mac.

Comment: And you've read the API documentation, not copied an example?

Comment: Yes I was going through the examples in the documentation.

Comment: Not what I asked, but did you see that note there? *Make sure proper versions of ffmpeg or gstreamer is installed.*

Comment: Yes I downloaded the latest version ffmpeg and added it to the /usr/local/bin folder. Though I am afraid it might have to do something with it further. That's why I asked the question if anybody else encountered it and if they did could this be solved anyhow. Btw how do I know which is the right version for my OS?

Comment: I assume that file exists in the current folder of your python script? And it's playable in a separate app?

Comment: Osx? `brew install ffmpeg`, assuming you're using Homebrew

Comment: Yeah file exists and plays fine on vlc. I installed using brew but still nothing. Should I restart my system?

Comment: Doesn't hurt, but I don't think it'll solve the problem. I still think you need to determine when and why that read function returns False

Comment: I don't understand the problem the same code runs fine on windows machine but not on mac. Also the VideoCapture works fine with camera feed.

Comment: Did you install with `pip install opencv-python`? Because if so, that's the problem. [See here for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46527000/webcam-does-not-work-in-pip-version-of-opencv-python-and-opencv-contrib-python/46527129#46527129).

Comment: Yeah seems something related to my problem. But I installed using conda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems avi format doesn't work with mac. Convert .avi file to .mp4 using 
`ffmpeg -i input.avi output.mp4` and use VideCapture('output.mp4') to capture the video file.